# how to scrape - span aria-hidden="true" - text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hidden-field

```html
 <div class="comments-post-meta__profile-info-wrapper display-flex">
    <a class="app-aware-link  inline-flex overflow-hidden t-16 t-black t-bold tap-target" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAAg-vkBuoZD8xeJW57GlPMiPRWUe-jvvSM" data-test-app-aware-link="">
      <h3 class="comments-post-meta__actor display-flex flex-column overflow-hidden t-12 t-normal t-black--light">
        <span class="comments-post-meta__name text-body-small-open t-black">
          <span class="comments-post-meta__name-text hoverable-link-text mr1">
            <span dir="ltr"><span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Nathan Greenhut<!----></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden"><!---->View Nathan Greenhut’s profile<!----></span>
          </span>
        </span>
</div>
```

I'm Trying to scrape the name of the people that commented on a particular LinkedIn post.

I tried this code:

```py
for i in soup.find_all("span",attrs = {"class" : "comments-post-meta__name-text hoverable-link-text mr1"}):
    print(i.find('span').get_text())
```

The output I got is:

```
Nathan GreenhutView Nathan Greenhut’s profile
```

But the Output I want is:

```
Nathan Greenhut
```

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: I think you forgot to specify the CSS attribute in `i.find('span')`. It should be `i.find('span', attrs={'dir': ltr})`

Comment: use the attribute info to select the right node, `soup.find("span", {"aria-hidden": "true"}).get_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the element directly by its attribute:

```
soup.find('span', {'aria-hidden': 'true'}).get_text(strip=True)
```

or by [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select_one('[aria-hidden="true"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

or if there are other elements with that kind of attribute being mor specific with:

```
soup.select_one('.comments-post-meta__profile-info-wrapper [aria-hidden="true"]').get_text(strip=True)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="comments-post-meta__profile-info-wrapper display-flex">
    <a class="app-aware-link  inline-flex overflow-hidden t-16 t-black t-bold tap-target" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAAg-vkBuoZD8xeJW57GlPMiPRWUe-jvvSM" data-test-app-aware-link="">
      <h3 class="comments-post-meta__actor display-flex flex-column overflow-hidden t-12 t-normal t-black--light">
        <span class="comments-post-meta__name text-body-small-open t-black">
          <span class="comments-post-meta__name-text hoverable-link-text mr1">
            <span dir="ltr"><span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Nathan Greenhut<!----></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden"><!---->View Nathan Greenhut’s profile<!----></span>
          </span>
        </span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('[aria-hidden="true"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution by going down the html structure using `find_next()`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    html =' <div class="comments-post-meta__profile-info-wrapper display-flex"><a class="app-aware-link  inline-flex overflow-hidden t-16 t-black t-bold tap-target" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAAg-vkBuoZD8xeJW57GlPMiPRWUe-jvvSM" data-test-app-aware-link=""><h3 class="comments-post-meta__actor display-flex flex-column overflow-hidden t-12 t-normal t-black--light"><span class="comments-post-meta__name text-body-small-open t-black"><span class="comments-post-meta__name-text hoverable-link-text mr1"><span dir="ltr"><span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Nathan Greenhut<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->View Nathan Greenhut’s profile<!----></span></span></span></div>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    comments_post = soup.find("span", "comments-post-meta__name-text hoverable-link-text mr1")
    comments_post_aria_hidden = comments_post.find("span", dir="ltr").find_next("span").text
    print(comments_post_aria_hidden)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
Nathan Greenhut
```